# How to test bot in different languages?

Tags: bots, chatbot, multilingual

We have a bot on dialogflow. The bot is setup in both languages - french and english.
It is not a problem to configure our botium instance in order to test all the intents in english (default language).

How to configure our botium instance in order to test all the intents in french?
My botium.json file contains now the capability like

**"DIALOGFLOW_LANGUAGE_CODE": "fr"**

When I run the botium cli command like

**botium-cli dialogflowimport --buildconvos=true**

I received convos and utterances in english.

Any workaround to get convos/utterances in french?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is something currently not implemented in the Botium Dialogflow connector. One of my team mates will take care of it in the next days.

Comment: Thank you Florian for this update. It would be nice to have the feature. Thanks a lot for this great tool!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the most recent Github commit it is now possible to import/export Botium data to and from Dialogflow in multiple languages - the *DIALOGFLOW_LANGUAGE_CODE*-capability is now respected. It is not part of the official release yet, so for now you have to install the latest version directly from Github:

```
npm install codeforequity-at/botium-connector-dialogflow#master
```

Comment: Thank you Florian for this update. It is good to have this feature in the official release. For now we made our bot as a single language bot. Thank you again.

Comment: Thank you Florian! It works! Thank you again for this great tool!